# Formato al obterner datos de un treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

estoy obteniendo datos de un Browse (treeview)de esta forma! Obtengo mis datos correctamente hasta que tengo regsitros que en el codigo comienzan por (0) Ejemplo: 0003, al obtener los datos el codigo retorna 3 sin los ceros por delante, al actualizar este tipo de registro en BD , no Sucede ya que no lo toma en cuenta pero si agrego los tres ceros si lo hago, en mi BD entan con los 000 ceros , como hago para poder obtener el valor como esta realmente en la BD

registros=BrowseProductos.item(BrowseProductos.focus())

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

'values': [1, '1+1 CON TROCITOS DE OREO 140 GRS', '12.0', '394.9', 'HOGAR', 'LINEA', 'SOPROLE', '359.0', '10.0', 0], 'open': 0,

De esta manera retorna el registro sin los ceros delantero

print desde consola listando desde la BD
('0001', '1+1 CON TROCITOS DE OREO 140 GRS', 12.0, 394.9, 'HOGAR', 'LINEA', 'SOPROLE', 359.0, 10.0, 0)

anexo codigo:

```
"""Funciones"""
def seleccionamos(tipo):
    try:
        """Seleccionamo"""
        registros=BrowseProductos.item(BrowseProductos.focus())
        
        """Pasamos los registros a variables"""
        codigo=registros['values'][0]
        descripcion=registros['values'][1]
        existencia=registros['values'][2]
        precio=registros['values'][3]
        departamento=registros['values'][4]
        linea=registros['values'][5]
        marca=registros['values'][6]
        costo=registros['values'][7]
        margen=registros['values'][8]
        maneja_iva=registros['values'][9]
        
        """Editar registro"""
        if tipo == "editar":
            buscarEntry.delete(0, END)
            """Retorna Tue al recibir actualizacion"""
            if EditarProd(lista ,codigo, descripcion, departamento, linea, marca, existencia, costo,
                   margen, precio, maneja_iva):
                buscarEntry.delete(0, END)
                buscar_productos('<Return>')
            
        """Eliminar registro"""
        if tipo == "eliminar":
            if mensajes.confirmar("Confirmar", f"Seguro que deseas eliminar el registro\n{descripcion}"):
                conectar().Eliminar_Productos(f'{codigo}')
                buscarEntry.delete(0, END)
                buscar_productos('<Return>')
                            
    except(IndexError) as e:
        pass

def buscar_productos(event):
    """Coloco el cursor en el entryBuscar"""
    buscarEntry.focus_set()
    
    def productos_stock():
        """Productos con extistecia 0"""
        if float(productos[2]) == 0.00:
            BrowseProductos.insert('',0, values=productos[0:10], tag="red")
        else:
            BrowseProductos.insert('',0, values=productos[0:10])

    """Listamos todos los productos con el for"""
    for productos in conectar().Listar_tbl_Productos():
        print(productos)
        """Recibo los datos"""
        codigo=productos[0]
        descripcion=productos[1]
        existencia=productos[2]
        precio=productos[3]
        departamento=productos[4]
        linea=productos[5]
        marca=productos[6]
        costo=productos[7]
        margen=productos[8]
        maneja_iva=productos[9]
        


        """Procedemos a realizar los filtros,
        si eñ entry de buscar no esta vacios,
        realiza las distintas operaciones
        """
        if not buscarEntry.get() == '':
            """Si el codigo de barra es de una Balanza,
            obtengo los digitos correspondinte a dicha balanza,
            en este caso la balanza comienza por '25'
            """
            if Buscar.get()[:2] == "25":
                """Valido los desde la posicion 2 a la 7,
                el cual seria el codigo del producto a buscar
                """
                if productos[0] == Buscar.get()[2:7]:
                    """Limpio el treeview"""
                    BrowseProductos.delete(*BrowseProductos.get_children())
                    """Identifico cada producto con el color rojo si el 
                    inventario = 0
                    """
                    productos_stock()
                    btnEditar.focus_set()
            """Buscamos los productos por codigo,
            """
            if productos[0] == Buscar.get():
                """Si el producto no tiene en existencia
                """
                BrowseProductos.delete(*BrowseProductos.get_children())
                productos_stock()
            """Buscamos descripcion indicando comodin * 
            Buscamos precio indicando comodin **
            Buscamos existencia indicando comodin ***
            """
            try:
                """Busqueda Por descripcion"""
                if Buscar.get()[0] == "*" and not Buscar.get()[1]=='*' and not Buscar.get()[2]=='*':
                    if re.search(buscarEntry.get()[1:].upper(), productos[1]):
                        productos_stock()
                """Busqueda por Precio"""
                if Buscar.get()[0] == "*" and Buscar.get()[1] == "*" and not Buscar.get()[2]=='*':
                    if float(Buscar.get()[2:]) == float(productos[3]):
                        productos_stock()
                """Busqueda por existecia"""
                if Buscar.get()[0] == "*" and Buscar.get()[1] == "*" and Buscar.get()[2] == "*" :
                    if float(Buscar.get()[3:]) == float(productos[2]):
                        productos_stock()
                """Precio Mayor que"""
                if Buscar.get()[0] == "*" and Buscar.get()[1]=='>':
                    if float(Buscar.get()[2:]) < float(productos[3]):
                        productos_stock()
                """Precio Menor que"""                                    
                if Buscar.get()[0] == "*" and Buscar.get()[1]=='<':
                    if float(Buscar.get()[2:]) > float(productos[3]):
                        productos_stock()
            except IndexError:
                pass
            
        else:
            """Mostramos todos los registros
            Los registros rojos , son sin existencia
            """
            productos_stock()
```

Comment: No estás aportando la información necesaria para saber qué te ocurre. Si desacoplas en el código la parte que accede a la base de datos de la que gestiona el interface tkinter, puedes probar la comunicación entre las dos partes para saber qué pasa con el dato '0003', si es de tipo string o se convierte en número, etc. ¿Has hecho algún test para comprobarlo?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu pregunta, si he echo pruebas e incluso <class 'str'>, cuando imprimo por consola todo perfecto , todo esta al recuperar los datos desde el mismo treeview.

{'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': [1, '1+1 CON TROCITOS DE OREO 140 GRS', '12.0', '394.9', 'HOGAR', 'LINEA', 'SOPROLE', '359.0', '10.0', 0], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}

con otro producto que no comienza por 0

{'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': [10105, 'AGUA AQUARIUS LIMONADA 1.6 LT', '12.0', '564.7', 'LICORES', 'NONE', 'COCACOLA', '504.2', '12.0', 0], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}

Comment: Hoy agregue una letra por delante de los codigos , y el mismo cambia el tipo de dato aun no se como hacer que siempre STR en ves de automatico {'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': ['M0003', 'ACEITE 100% VEGETAL BELMONT 250 ML', '0.0', '750.0', 'VARIOS', 'None', 'VARIOS', '0.0', '0.0', 'None'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ['red']}